# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Live Player Error List Bug

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamaring Live Player to build and deploy / test directly on my android device as I'm editing the layout. The problem is every time I stop typing for a second or try to open up intelisense to check for parameters it compiles, builds and shows errors in syntax (obviously since I didnt finish writing the line).

This wouldnt be a problem but it automatically focuses the Error List so in order to continue typing code I have to click on the code window which is very annoying. I can deploy it manually every time (not live update) but this is very annoying aswell since I dont want to hit debug every time I change a margin for 5 pixels..

I tried: Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > General and disabled "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors" restarted the studio but it appears every time.. Even when I hide it or close it pops right back up.

Did anyone have this problem? Does anyone know a solution?